# SQL - Join two tables without a key

Tags: sql, oracle, select, join

Given two tables (`count(Table1) <= count(Table2)`):

Table1:

```
record-1 
record-2 
... 
record-k
```

Table2:

```
promo-1
promo-2
...
promo-j
```

Is it possible to join them into the following table? I.e. assign each entry in `Table1` some entry in `Table2`, but that no two entries in `Table1` would correspond to the same entry in `Table2`.

Result:

```
record-1    promo-i1
record-2    promo-i2
...
record-n    promo-in
```

Comment: By which criteria do you want to join records? Why is record-2 joined to promo-i2 and not to, say, promo-i18 for instance?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner No criteria, entries in Table2 may be chosen arbitrarily.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a fake key using the `rownum` pseudo-column, and join according to that:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM   (SELECT   col1, ROWNUM AS rn
        FROM     table1
        ORDER BY col1) t1
JOIN   (SELECT   col2, ROWNUM AS rn
        FROM     table2
        ORDER BY col2) t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

**EDIT:**

A slightly "clunkier", yet more ANSI-friendly approach would be to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
SELECT t1.col1, t2.col2
FROM   (SELECT   col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS rn
        FROM     table1) t1
JOIN   (SELECT   col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col2) AS rn
        FROM     table2) t2 ON t1.rn = t2.rn
```

Comment: Why do we need order by in sub-queries?

Comment: If the records to join can be chosen arbitrarily, you don't need an order by clause. (But I think for the ROW_NUMBER function it's mandatory.) BTW: If one table can have more records than the other and you want to see records you don't find a pair for, you can outer join: ` from (select ...) full outer join (select ...)`.